# partial differentiation and quotient rule

Tags: matrices, partial-derivative

I want to compute a partial differentiation $\frac{\partial A}{\partial q}$ where A is ($\ddot{q}$), the output of standard manipulator equation, i.e.

$$ H(q)\ddot q + C(q,\dot q)\dot q+G(q) =0 $$

$A = (C*\dot{\theta} + G)/H $ and $q$ is a vector $[q_1 q_2 q_3 q_4]$. 
Also C and H are $2\times2$ matrices and G is a $2\times1$ matrix with elements function of $q$. My problem is, as division is involved (computed as matrix inverse), how should I compute the partial differentiation? Should I apply the quotient rule? And if I apply the quotient rule then I am unable to compute the numerator as the matrices are turning out such that I cannot multiply them.

Thanks.

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial q}(H^{-1}(q))=-H^{-1}(q)\frac{\partial}{\partial q}(H(q))H^{-1}(q)$

Comment: Thankyou for your reply, but can you please elaborate, I really didn't understand your reply. and by $\theta$ do you mean $\partial$.

Comment: Ok, I will post an answer.

Comment: OK now I understand,  but if $H$ is a $2*2$ matrix $\frac{\partial H}{\partial q} $ turns out to be $2*8$ matrix, cant multiply with other matrices.

Comment: I meant $\frac{\partial}{\partial q_i} H^{-1}(q)=-H^{-1}(q) \frac{\partial}{\partial q_i} (H(q))H^{-1}(q)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\ddot{q}=A(q,\dot{q}):=-H^{-1}(q)[C(q,\dot{q})\dot{q}+G(q)]$$
So your derivative is a matrix with matrix elements i.e.
$$\frac{\partial A(q,\dot{q})}{\partial q}=\left[\matrix{\frac{\partial A(q,\dot{q})}{\partial q_i}}\right] $$
and each element has the form
$$\frac{\partial A(q,\dot{q})}{\partial q_i}=\frac{\partial}{\partial q_i}\left\{H^{-1}(q)C(q,\dot{q})\dot{q}\right\}+\frac{\partial}{\partial q_i}\left\{H^{-1}(q)G(q)\right\}=\frac{\partial}{\partial q_i}\left\{H^{-1}(q)\right\}C(q,\dot{q})\dot{q}+H^{-1}(q)\frac{\partial}{\partial q_i}\left\{C(q,\dot{q})\right\}\dot{q}+\frac{\partial}{\partial q_i}\left\{H^{-1}(q)\right\}G(q)+H^{-1}(q)\frac{\partial}{\partial q_i}\left\{G(q)\right\}=-H^{-1}(q)\frac{\partial}{\partial q_i}(H(q))H^{-1}(q)[C(q,\dot{q})\dot{q}+G(q)]+H^{-1}(q)\frac{\partial}{\partial q_i}\left\{C(q,\dot{q})\right\}\dot{q}+H^{-1}(q)\frac{\partial}{\partial q_i}\left\{G(q)\right\}=H^{-1}(q)\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial q_i}\left\{C(q,\dot{q})\right\}\dot{q}+\frac{\partial}{\partial q_i}\left\{G(q)\right\}-\frac{\partial}{\partial q_i}\{H(q)\}H^{-1}(q)\left[C(q,\dot{q})\dot{q}+G(q)\right]\right]$$
Note that each $\frac{\partial A(q,\dot{q})}{\partial q_i}$ is a $2\times 1$ vector so your overall derivative can be either a $4\times 1$ vector or a $2\times 2$ matrix.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. That clears a lot. Only one question though, in the terms $\frac{\partial}{\partial q} {C(q,\dot{q})}$ and the term  $\frac{\partial}{\partial q} {H(q)}$ when I differentiate with each of the term in the $q$ vector i.e $\frac{\partial H(1,1)}{\partial q_1} , \frac{\partial H(1,1)}{\partial q_2} ,\frac{\partial H(1,1)}{\partial q_3} ,\frac{\partial H(1,1)}{\partial q_4}$. This generate 4 terms like a jacobian. So,  it becomes  jacobian of matrix by matrix (instead of vector by vector) then matrices created aren't adding  or am I missing something.

Comment: Sorry for above question, had a re-look at your reply and I think it makes sense. I will implement it on Matlab now. Cheers.

Comment: Hi CTNT, I computed the final equ and as you say the o/p for one $\frac{\partial A}{\partial q1}$ comes up to be a $2 * 1$ matrix, but now that I have 4 such $2 * 1$ matrices how do I append them to make a $2 * 2$ matrix as you said?

Comment: Do you  also calculate the partial derivatives for $\dot{q}$? Since $C$ and $H$ are $2\times 2$ matrices $q$ must also be a $2\times 1 $ vector.

Comment: ohh yes, $q$ is a vector made up of four variables $[q_1, q_2, q_3,q_4]$
where $[q_3, q_4]$ is q_dot(1:2) ; i.e I am giving this vector to matlab ODE45. and I need to calculate $ \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{q}}$ where f is basically $[q ,\dot{q}]$. Have I confused you?

Comment: Well, then you have to calculate similarly as above the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial A}{\partial \dot{q}_i}$

Comment: OK... it works out then.....thanks a lot for your help though. It would have taken me ages to figure out the solution you gave. Cheers.